# "Careful" to mean "make sure"

Tags: word-usage

I have used a sentence like "Be careful of wearing a coat." and I wondered if it was a normal sentence a native speaker would say.
Looking at the OALD, I noticed the following example:

> I'm very careful about washing my hands before eating.

The dictionary adds between parentheses:

> I make sure I do it.

Does that mean *be careful* can be used to mean "make sure"? Would my example sentence be understood to mean "Be sure to wear a coat."?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some contexts, "to be careful" can be used to mean "I have an ongoing habit of making sure I do [x]".  This is the case in your hand-washing example; ***"I'm very careful about washing my hands before eating"*** means ***"I always make sure to wash my hands before I eat".***

It doesn't work quite the same way in a command, though.  If you're telling someone to *be careful* about/while doing something, you're cautioning them.  For example, "Be careful when you cross the street!" is said to make sure someone uses caution and isn't hit by a car, not to tell them to be sure to cross the street.

So, in your example sentence:

> "Be careful of wearing a coat."

This doesn't mean "Be sure to wear a coat", but actually the opposite; it's a caution *against* wearing a coat.  It would be understood as:

> "Take caution when you wear a coat! When you wear coats bad things can happen, and you need to watch out."

Which is probably not what you mean to imply!

Comment: But "*Be careful **to** wear a coat.*" **does** mean to make sure you wear one.

Comment: @Jim: excellent point. Be careful of using the wrong preposition. Be careful to use the right one.

Comment: @Jim I don't know that I'd expect that sentence from a native. 'Be careful *and* wear a coat', maybe.  But that separates the care and the coat, so isn't in OP's scope.

Comment: @mcalex- https://www.google.com/search?q=%22be%20careful%20to%20wear%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en#hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22be+careful+to+wear+a%22&oq=%22be+careful+to+wear+a%22&gs_l=serp.3...1269818.1272012.0.1272901.4.4.0.0.0.0.425.801.2j1j4-1.4.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.t2UNI99GeOQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.b2I&fp=ef5136a30ad79726&biw=1359&bih=751